# Paypal ios initialization crashed my app

Tags: ios, iphone, paypal, ios9

I am using the paypal ios sdk version 2.12.0 and when I am calling the paypal initialization method in appdelegate

```
[PayPalMobile initializeWithClientIdsForEnvironments:@{PayPalEnvironmentSandbox : @"x"}];
```

and from appdelegate when I push the loginscreen after some time the app crashed and there is no log also only the execution halts at the CFRealease and when this code is commented the app works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is an [issue on paypal repository](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/issues/351)  (but for another iOS version)  . Try to use 2.12.4 version instead of 2.12.0.

Answer (score 0):

use recent library form there

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK